# How to verify this given homeomorphism in Munkres on stereographic projection

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

In munkres topology for theorem 59.3, he provided a homeomorphism between $S^n- p$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$,
where
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 - x_{n+1}} (x_1, \dots , x_n)$$
and
$$f^{-1}(y) = (t(y)y_1, \dots , t(y)y_n, 1- t(y))$$
given $t(y) = \frac{2}{1+ ||y||^2}$.
how do I check that they are actually the inverse of each other?
(I tried to plug in one to the other, but he algebra is just horrible.)
(This is on page 369 in munkres)

Comment: It should be $1-x_{n+1}$ in the denominator.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stereographic+projection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dispute the "horror" of the algebra. For $f^{-1}(f(x))$, let's write $a$ for $1/(1-x_{n+1})$. Then $y_i=ax_i$ and
$$\|y\|^2=a^2\|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\|^2=a^2(1-x_{n+1}^2)=\frac{1+x_{n+1}}{1-x_{n+1}}$$
and
$$1+\|y\|^2=\frac2{1-x_{n+1}}$$
since $x$ is on the unit sphere. Then
$$t=t(y)=\frac2{1+\|y\|^2}=1-x_{n+1}.$$
So
$$f^{-1}(y)=((1-x_{n+1})y_1,\ldots,(1-x_{n+1})y_n,x_{n+1})=x$$
since $x_i=(1-x_{n+1})y_i$.

Doing $f(f^{-1}(y))$ is no more difficult.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do the other direction?  Thanks

Comment: Oh i got it! never mind thank you for your help!